# Unable to scale element to 100% width

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to set the image I put in my page to 100% width, but something in the left always leaves whitespace.  I tried

```
.coverImage {
         width: 100vw;
   }
```

That didn't work out, so I used:

```
.coverImage {
         width: 100%;
   }
```

But nothing seems to work. Also, I have white space only on the left side. The attatched screenshots are  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV9r0.jpg). This screenshot also shows the script.

Comment: What about margins?

Comment: you have margin set on the upper element

Comment: Add your html markup or create a snippet so that we can help you identify the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML actually has basic CSS already "built in" to it. If you create an index.html, and only have `<h1>hello there</h1>`, you'll see it's big and bold. There's also default margins, which is probably what you're experiencing.

You can do mazunki's answer of setting margin to 0,

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

This resets all your junk to have 0 margin, but something I like to include when working in CSS is a reset.css file. What this file does is resets **all** the basic HTML styling, so you never have to deal with it in the future of working on your project.

You can slap this bad-boy at the beginning of your css file, or make a separate reset.css file. If you make its own file, be sure to import it *before* your actual css file in your html.

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
font-size: 100%;
font: inherit;
vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
display: block;
}
body {
line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
content: '';
content: none;
}
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
}
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
```

Good luck!

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked for you. I slap this reset.css on everything web I do. Don't forget to mark the answer!

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting your margins:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

The reason I set the width to 100% for html and body is to ensure the width % of your picture streches to the full viewport, as a percentage size (and `em` sizes, kind of) is relative to its parent.

Comment: The margins and paddings should be reset obly for the html and body. Removing all margins and paddings by default can cause issues if the stylesheet is refferenced after other stylesheets.

Comment: While I agree it's dangerous, it's always the first thing I do once I start a new project. I prefer to have full control, and not be platform dependent. Doing it for all elements on an already initiated document may be tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Your width is set to '100vh' which means it is as wide as your screens height, change this to '100vw' and add 'margin:0;'

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out. Thanks!